# How to write a SQL query to retrieve all those customers whose age in months is more than 200 months?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to write a SQL/Oracle query to retrieve all those customers whose age in months is more than 200 months?
I have a exam on Monday but I am having some confusion with months and dates calculation.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle-11g? I doubt you're using both.

Comment: Yes, I am using Oracle 11g and MySQL.

Comment: Which one do you need to do this in?

Comment: Thanks for time and attention. I am new on this site. I am feeling please and happy to get help from you and the  others great people around the world.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Query like this for MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE bithdayField <= NOW() - INTERVAL 200 MONTH;
```

Comment: Birthday and birthdate field doesn't exist in tables.

Comment: @Hyder That's a placeholder, replace it with whatever the actual field name is.

Comment: @Barmar,Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is the same (the date is older than *today minus 200 months*), but the actual SQL is usually different, because DBMSes have a large variation of syntax in the date/time area.

Standard SQL & MySQL:

```
WHERE datecol < current_date - interval '200' month
```

Oracle:

```
WHERE datecol < add_months(current_date, -200)
```

In fact Oracle also supports the Standard SQL version, but it's not recommended, because you might get an invalid date error when you do something like `'2018-03-31' - interval '1' month`. This is based on a (dumb) Standard SQL rule which MySQL doesn't follow: *one month before March 31 was February 31, oops, that date doesn't exists*.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle DB, there are two nice functions : [months_between](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/months_between.php) and [add_months](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php)
been used for these type date calculations. For your case, you may use one of the following :

```
select id, name, surname
  from customers
 where months_between(trunc(sysdate),DOB)>200;
```

*or*

```
 select id, name, surname
  from customers
 where add_months(trunc(sysdate),-200)>DOB;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1c7e/6)